# Firefox Transition easeinandout

Tags: html, css, firefox, transition

I can't get an image to fade in and out with the transition thing in css. Can somebody see the problem? I'm not trying to get the background transitioned only the img that has a hover on it.

```css
.icongestaltung{
  background: url(images/startpageicon_draw.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;

    width: 8em;
    height: 8em;
    float: left;
    
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;    
}
.icongestaltung:hover{
    background-image:url("images/startpageicon_gestaltungunddesign.png");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
            <div class="startpageicons">
                <div class="icongestaltung">   
                </div>
           </div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: nope my problem seem different. Or the description of the other problem is not good.

Comment: Did you check the answer that has the most votes there? Did you read it completely?

Comment: No it didn't work for my situation

Comment: Of course it didn't work. It said that there is an open bug in firefox! I asked if you read it **completely**... please do so.

Comment: Of course I have read it. Just thought that there must be an alternative! :/

Comment: There are alternatives using javascript, but for css - there is an open bug there, and it's in the answer.